# Bash checking if IP/Port is UP

Tags: linux, bash

im trying to check with a bash script the status of an IP/Port via netstat. Unfortunately it dont works ... I get an exit 1 even if it should be exit 0.

```
RUNBOT=$(netstat -tulpen |grep ${IP}:${PORT} | wc -l)

    if [ "${RUNBOT} = "1" ]; then
            echo "Bot ${IP}:${PORT} is running!"        
        exit 0
    else
            echo "Bot ${IP}:${PORT} is NOT running!"
        exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: First of all you are missing an `"` at `"${RUNBOT} = "1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lsof -ni @${IP}:${PORT} >/dev/null
b=$?
if [ $b = 0 ]; then
            echo "Bot ${IP}:${PORT} is running!"        
        exit 0
    else
            echo "Bot ${IP}:${PORT} is NOT running!"
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: lsof is not always installed in all distributions.
additionally it can take quite long to generate such a list.